# Add event handler to HTML element using javascript

Tags: javascript

I want to add an event handler to a paragraph for when any user clicks on it. For example, I have a paragraph which would show an alert when a user clicks it, but without using "onclick" on HTML.

```
 <p id="p1">This is paragraph Click here..</p>
 <a href="http://www.google.com" id="link1" >test</a>
 document.getElementById('p1').onmouseover  = paragraphHTML;
```

Comment: <p id="p1">This is paragraph Click here..</p>
        <br />
        <a href="http://www.google.com" id="link1" >test</a>

       <script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById('p1').onmouseover  = paragraphHTML; // no parentheses in paragraphHTML  
   
 function paragraphHTML()  
 {  
     alert(this.innerHTML);  
 }  
   
    
    </script>

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can add event listener.
Smth. like this:

```
 var el = document.getElementById("p1");
if (el.addEventListener) {
        el.addEventListener("click", yourFunction, false);
    } else {
        el.attachEvent('onclick', yourFunction);
    }
```

(thanks @Reorx)

[Explanation Here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.addEventListener)

Complete code (tested in Chrome&IE7):

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title></title>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1255">
        <script type="text/javascript">
            window.onload =function (){
            var el = document.getElementById("p1");
            if (el.addEventListener) {
                el.addEventListener("click", yourFunction, false);
            } else {
                el.attachEvent('onclick', yourFunction);
            }
            };
            function yourFunction(){
                alert("test");
            }
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p id="p1">test</p>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi its working in firefox but Ie there is a problem its says   Object doesn't support this property or method

Comment: you said you don't want "onclick" event to p1. Did u? el.addEventListener("click", yourFunction, false) is adding event to "onclick"

Comment: @Jun1st: mmm. you are right. as far as I understood adilahmed just didn't want it to be inline

Comment: Hi all  i did like this for work in both firefox and Ie but its only woking in Firefox

Comment: @adilahmed: works perfect in Chrome. What error do you get? Where do you add the script? Inside window.onload function?

Comment: Hi check above its not wokring in IE

Comment: What is the `false` for?

Answer (score 6):

To suit most situations, you can write a function to handle this:

```
var bindEvent = function(element, type, handler) {
    if (element.addEventListener) {
        element.addEventListener(type, handler, false);
    } else {
        element.attachEvent('on'+type, handler);
    }
}
```

Comment: In IE this function will find the element for binding has no attribute 'addEventListener', then the handler will be assigned to its 'onTYPE' attribute, eg, 'onclick'.

Answer (score 1):

Add a `tabIndex` attribute to your `p` element, then you can use the `onfocus` function.

demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9y7CL/