# how to add click event to a hugely populated color table

Tags: javascript

i have got a huge color chart .it is a densely populated color chart made of  many individual table block element of different bgColor.i want to add click event to each of them so that i can use them according to my choice.it is tedious to add onClick event to each and every one of them.how it can be done with less codes using only javascript?

FULL CODE:

```
<html>
<head>
<style>
*{margin:0px;padding:0px;}
#colorchart{width:400px;height:400px;}
</style>
</head>
<body>

<table id="colorchart" >
 <tr><td bgColor="#FBEFEF"></td><td bgColor="#FBF2EF"></td><td bgColor="#FBF5EF"></td><td bgColor="#FBF8EF"></td><td bgColor="#FBFBEF"></td><td bgColor="#F8FBEF"></td><td bgColor="#F5FBEF"></td><td bgColor="#F2FBEF"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBEF"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBF2"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBF5"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBF8"></td><td bgColor="#EFFBFB"></td><td bgColor="#EFF8FB"></td><td bgColor="#EFF5FB"></td><td bgColor="#EFF2FB"></td><td bgColor="#EFEFFB"></td><td bgColor="#F2EFFB"></td><td bgColor="#F5EFFB"></td><td bgColor="#F8EFFB"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFFB"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFF8"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFF5"></td><td bgColor="#FBEFF2"></td><td bgColor="#FFFFFF"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F8E0E0"></td><td bgColor="#F8E6E0"></td><td bgColor="#F8ECE0"></td><td bgColor="#F7F2E0"></td><td bgColor="#F7F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#F1F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#ECF8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E6F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8E0"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8E6"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8EC"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8F1"></td><td bgColor="#E0F8F7"></td><td bgColor="#E0F2F7"></td><td bgColor="#E0ECF8"></td><td bgColor="#E0E6F8"></td><td bgColor="#E0E0F8"></td><td bgColor="#E6E0F8"></td><td bgColor="#ECE0F8"></td><td bgColor="#F2E0F7"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0F7"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0F1"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0EC"></td><td bgColor="#F8E0E6"></td><td bgColor="#FAFAFA"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F6CECE"></td><td bgColor="#F6D8CE"></td><td bgColor="#F6E3CE"></td><td bgColor="#F5ECCE"></td><td bgColor="#F5F6CE"></td><td bgColor="#ECF6CE"></td><td bgColor="#E3F6CE"></td><td bgColor="#D8F6CE"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6CE"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6D8"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6E3"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6EC"></td><td bgColor="#CEF6F5"></td><td bgColor="#CEECF5"></td><td bgColor="#CEE3F6"></td><td bgColor="#CED8F6"></td><td bgColor="#CECEF6"></td><td bgColor="#D8CEF6"></td><td bgColor="#E3CEF6"></td><td bgColor="#ECCEF5"></td><td bgColor="#F6CEF5"></td><td bgColor="#F6CEEC"></td><td bgColor="#F6CEE3"></td><td bgColor="#F6CED8"></td><td bgColor="#F2F2F2"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F5A9A9"></td><td bgColor="#F5BCA9"></td><td bgColor="#F5D0A9"></td><td bgColor="#F3E2A9"></td><td bgColor="#F2F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#E1F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#D0F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#BCF5A9"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5A9"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5BC"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5D0"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5E1"></td><td bgColor="#A9F5F2"></td><td bgColor="#A9E2F3"></td><td bgColor="#A9D0F5"></td><td bgColor="#A9BCF5"></td><td bgColor="#A9A9F5"></td><td bgColor="#BCA9F5"></td><td bgColor="#D0A9F5"></td><td bgColor="#E2A9F3"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9F2"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9E1"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9D0"></td><td bgColor="#F5A9BC"></td><td bgColor="#E6E6E6"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#F78181"></td><td bgColor="#F79F81"></td><td bgColor="#F7BE81"></td><td bgColor="#F5DA81"></td><td bgColor="#F3F781"></td><td bgColor="#D8F781"></td><td bgColor="#BEF781"></td><td bgColor="#9FF781"></td><td bgColor="#81F781"></td><td bgColor="#81F79F"></td><td bgColor="#81F7BE"></td><td bgColor="#81F7D8"></td><td bgColor="#81F7F3"></td><td bgColor="#81DAF5"></td><td bgColor="#81BEF7"></td><td bgColor="#819FF7"></td><td bgColor="#8181F7"></td><td bgColor="#9F81F7"></td><td bgColor="#BE81F7"></td><td bgColor="#DA81F5"></td><td bgColor="#F781F3"></td><td bgColor="#F781D8"></td><td bgColor="#F781BE"></td><td bgColor="#F7819F"></td><td bgColor="#D8D8D8"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#FA5858"></td><td bgColor="#FA8258"></td><td bgColor="#FAAC58"></td><td bgColor="#F7D358"></td><td bgColor="#F4FA58"></td><td bgColor="#D0FA58"></td><td bgColor="#ACFA58"></td><td bgColor="#82FA58"></td><td bgColor="#58FA58"></td><td bgColor="#58FA82"></td><td bgColor="#58FAAC"></td><td bgColor="#58FAD0"></td><td bgColor="#58FAF4"></td><td bgColor="#58D3F7"></td><td bgColor="#58ACFA"></td><td bgColor="#5882FA"></td><td bgColor="#5858FA"></td><td bgColor="#8258FA"></td><td bgColor="#AC58FA"></td><td bgColor="#D358F7"></td><td bgColor="#FA58F4"></td><td bgColor="#FA58D0"></td><td bgColor="#FA58AC"></td><td bgColor="#FA5882"></td><td bgColor="#BDBDBD"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#FE2E2E"></td><td bgColor="#FE642E"></td><td bgColor="#FE9A2E"></td><td bgColor="#FACC2E"></td><td bgColor="#F7FE2E"></td><td bgColor="#C8FE2E"></td><td bgColor="#9AFE2E"></td><td bgColor="#64FE2E"></td><td bgColor="#2EFE2E"></td><td bgColor="#2EFE64"></td><td bgColor="#2EFE9A"></td><td bgColor="#2EFEC8"></td><td bgColor="#2EFEF7"></td><td bgColor="#2ECCFA"></td><td bgColor="#2E9AFE"></td><td bgColor="#2E64FE"></td><td bgColor="#2E2EFE"></td><td bgColor="#642EFE"></td><td bgColor="#9A2EFE"></td><td bgColor="#CC2EFA"></td><td bgColor="#FE2EF7"></td><td bgColor="#FE2EC8"></td><td bgColor="#FE2E9A"></td><td bgColor="#FE2E64"></td><td bgColor="#A4A4A4"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#FF0000"></td><td bgColor="#FF4000"></td><td bgColor="#FF8000"></td><td bgColor="#FFBF00"></td><td bgColor="#FFFF00"></td><td bgColor="#BFFF00"></td><td bgColor="#80FF00"></td><td bgColor="#40FF00"></td><td bgColor="#00FF00"></td><td bgColor="#00FF40"></td><td bgColor="#00FF80"></td><td bgColor="#00FFBF"></td><td bgColor="#00FFFF"></td><td bgColor="#00BFFF"></td><td bgColor="#0080FF"></td><td bgColor="#0040FF"></td><td bgColor="#0000FF"></td><td bgColor="#4000FF"></td><td bgColor="#8000FF"></td><td bgColor="#BF00FF"></td><td bgColor="#FF00FF"></td><td bgColor="#FF00BF"></td><td bgColor="#FF0080"></td><td bgColor="#FF0040"></td><td bgColor="#848484"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#DF0101"></td><td bgColor="#DF3A01"></td><td bgColor="#DF7401"></td><td bgColor="#DBA901"></td><td bgColor="#D7DF01"></td><td bgColor="#A5DF00"></td><td bgColor="#74DF00"></td><td bgColor="#3ADF00"></td><td bgColor="#01DF01"></td><td bgColor="#01DF3A"></td><td bgColor="#01DF74"></td><td bgColor="#01DFA5"></td><td bgColor="#01DFD7"></td><td bgColor="#01A9DB"></td><td bgColor="#0174DF"></td><td bgColor="#013ADF"></td><td bgColor="#0101DF"></td><td bgColor="#3A01DF"></td><td bgColor="#7401DF"></td><td bgColor="#A901DB"></td><td bgColor="#DF01D7"></td><td bgColor="#DF01A5"></td><td bgColor="#DF0174"></td><td bgColor="#DF013A"></td><td bgColor="#6E6E6E"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#B40404"></td><td bgColor="#B43104"></td><td bgColor="#B45F04"></td><td bgColor="#B18904"></td><td bgColor="#AEB404"></td><td bgColor="#86B404"></td><td bgColor="#5FB404"></td><td bgColor="#31B404"></td><td bgColor="#04B404"></td><td bgColor="#04B431"></td><td bgColor="#04B45F"></td><td bgColor="#04B486"></td><td bgColor="#04B4AE"></td><td bgColor="#0489B1"></td><td bgColor="#045FB4"></td><td bgColor="#0431B4"></td><td bgColor="#0404B4"></td><td bgColor="#3104B4"></td><td bgColor="#5F04B4"></td><td bgColor="#8904B1"></td><td bgColor="#B404AE"></td><td bgColor="#B40486"></td><td bgColor="#B4045F"></td><td bgColor="#B40431"></td><td bgColor="#585858"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#8A0808"></td><td bgColor="#8A2908"></td><td bgColor="#8A4B08"></td><td bgColor="#886A08"></td><td bgColor="#868A08"></td><td bgColor="#688A08"></td><td bgColor="#4B8A08"></td><td bgColor="#298A08"></td><td bgColor="#088A08"></td><td bgColor="#088A29"></td><td bgColor="#088A4B"></td><td bgColor="#088A68"></td><td bgColor="#088A85"></td><td bgColor="#086A87"></td><td bgColor="#084B8A"></td><td bgColor="#08298A"></td><td bgColor="#08088A"></td><td bgColor="#29088A"></td><td bgColor="#4B088A"></td><td bgColor="#6A0888"></td><td bgColor="#8A0886"></td><td bgColor="#8A0868"></td><td bgColor="#8A084B"></td><td bgColor="#8A0829"></td><td bgColor="#424242"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#610B0B"></td><td bgColor="#61210B"></td><td bgColor="#61380B"></td><td bgColor="#5F4C0B"></td><td bgColor="#5E610B"></td><td bgColor="#4B610B"></td><td bgColor="#38610B"></td><td bgColor="#21610B"></td><td bgColor="#0B610B"></td><td bgColor="#0B6121"></td><td bgColor="#0B6138"></td><td bgColor="#0B614B"></td><td bgColor="#0B615E"></td><td bgColor="#0B4C5F"></td><td bgColor="#0B3861"></td><td bgColor="#0B2161"></td><td bgColor="#0B0B61"></td><td bgColor="#210B61"></td><td bgColor="#380B61"></td><td bgColor="#4C0B5F"></td><td bgColor="#610B5E"></td><td bgColor="#610B4B"></td><td bgColor="#610B38"></td><td bgColor="#610B21"></td><td bgColor="#2E2E2E"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#3B0B0B"></td><td bgColor="#3B170B"></td><td bgColor="#3B240B"></td><td bgColor="#3A2F0B"></td><td bgColor="#393B0B"></td><td bgColor="#2E3B0B"></td><td bgColor="#243B0B"></td><td bgColor="#173B0B"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B0B"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B17"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B24"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B2E"></td><td bgColor="#0B3B39"></td><td bgColor="#0B2F3A"></td><td bgColor="#0B243B"></td><td bgColor="#0B173B"></td><td bgColor="#0B0B3B"></td><td bgColor="#170B3B"></td><td bgColor="#240B3B"></td><td bgColor="#2F0B3A"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B39"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B2E"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B24"></td><td bgColor="#3B0B17"></td><td bgColor="#1C1C1C"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#2A0A0A"></td><td bgColor="#2A120A"></td><td bgColor="#2A1B0A"></td><td bgColor="#29220A"></td><td bgColor="#292A0A"></td><td bgColor="#222A0A"></td><td bgColor="#1B2A0A"></td><td bgColor="#122A0A"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A0A"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A12"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A1B"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A22"></td><td bgColor="#0A2A29"></td><td bgColor="#0A2229"></td><td bgColor="#0A1B2A"></td><td bgColor="#0A122A"></td><td bgColor="#0A0A2A"></td><td bgColor="#120A2A"></td><td bgColor="#1B0A2A"></td><td bgColor="#220A29"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A29"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A22"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A1B"></td><td bgColor="#2A0A12"></td><td bgColor="#151515"></td></tr>
 <tr><td bgColor="#190707"></td><td bgColor="#190B07"></td><td bgColor="#191007"></td><td bgColor="#181407"></td><td bgColor="#181907"></td><td bgColor="#141907"></td><td bgColor="#101907"></td><td bgColor="#0B1907"></td><td bgColor="#071907"></td><td bgColor="#07190B"></td><td bgColor="#071910"></td><td bgColor="#071914"></td><td bgColor="#071918"></td><td bgColor="#071418"></td><td bgColor="#071019"></td><td bgColor="#070B19"></td><td bgColor="#070719"></td><td bgColor="#0B0719"></td><td bgColor="#100719"></td><td bgColor="#140718"></td><td bgColor="#190718"></td><td bgColor="#190714"></td><td bgColor="#190710"></td><td bgColor="#19070B"></td><td bgColor="#000000"></td></tr>
</table>
<script>
var table = document.getElementById('colorchart');
table.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var target = event.target||event.srcElement;
  if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
    // work on target which is the clicked <td>
    alert(target.bgColor);
  }
}, false);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You dont need to add a handler to each td. Events bubble. So you only need one handler on the `<table>`.

Add the clickhandler to the `<tabel>`. Inside it you have the `event` which has a `target` pointing to the clicked `<td>`.

```
<table onclick="func(event)">...


function func(event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName == 'TD') { // td was clicked
    // do something with the td
  }
;
```

Or add the event using DOM:

```
var table = document.getElementById('colorchart');
table.addEventListener('click', function (event) {
  var target = event.target;
  if (target.tagName == 'TD') {
    // work on target which is the clicked <td>
  }
}, false);
```

Comment: though it is not working in opera and ie11.even the color chart is not loading in opera :(

Comment: in IE you may have to do: `var target = event.target || event.srcElement`. I dont have IE here so i cant test.

Comment: i don't know what's happen!! but opera is not even showing the color chart.and event.srcElement is not working with ie

Comment: Then you have other errors in your page. Unless you show your code its impossible to help.

Comment: ok i am going to edit my topic.i will include full code there.i only made an alert to show the bfColor hex code

Comment: I updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/U8P7d/2/ and it works for me. I will not work in IE8 because there is no `addEventListener` in this Browser.

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to add one click handler to each td element. On click you then just have to read the bgColor-attribute. See here:

[Add event handler to HTML element using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800310/add-event-handler-to-html-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1):

Are you looking for this?

```
window.onload = function(){ 
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName('td'); 
    for (var i = 0; i < x.length; i++) {
        x[i].addEventListener('click', function(){console.log(this.bgColor);}, false);
    }
};
```

Check out this fiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/up74z/

Answer (score 1):

Try with this:

```
var table = document.getElementById('colorchart');
var tds   = table.getElementsByTagName('td');

for( actTd in tds ){
    tds[actTd].onclick = function(){
        console.log("color: " + this.getAttribute('bgColor'));
    }
}
```

You can find the working [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aSx7g/)