# show/hide div using toggle function onclick?

Tags: javascript, css, toggle

I am trying to show a `div` using `javascript` when a user clicks on another `div`.

Here is my code, its working fine, except, I need it to work the other way around. The `div` is visible on load and hidden once the user clicks the other `div`.

```
<div id="content_nav">
  <div class="login_heading">Logged in as, <strong><?php echo $_SESSION['user'];?>>/strong>, <a href="logout.php">Logout</a></div>
  <div class="control_panel">
    <div id="ctrl1" onclick="toggle();"></div>
    <p class="control">(0) Messages</p>
    <div id="msg_menu"></div>

    <script>
     var toggle = function() {
       var mydiv = document.getElementById('msg_menu');
       if (mydiv.style.display === 'none' || mydiv.style.display === '')
         mydiv.style.display = 'block';
       else
         mydiv.style.display = 'none'
     }
    </script>
```

css:

```
#msg_menu{
   margin:auto;
   width:990px;
   height:200px;
   background:#000;
}
```

Comment: You must register and unregister click event handler. Consider using jquery `on` and `off`.

Comment: is there a jquery alternative?

Comment: of course, here is with pure javascript: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800310/add-event-handler-to-html-element-using-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Modify your css such, that the element is hidden by default.  It can then be toggled on/off by the user as required.

```
#msg_menu{
   margin:auto;
   width:990px;
   height:200px;
   background:#000;
   display:none;
}
```

Alternatively, if you prefer a javascript solution, then you can hide the element when it's loaded.