# Dropdown is not updating while selecting another value

Tags: javascript

Hello in my form I have used **java script** **on change** event it's working for my textboxes but not working for my dropdown-box, whenever I'm selecting from drop down other

values it must change but it's not working

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
    <head>

        <script type="text/javascript">

            function add() 
            {
                var ea   = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.earnamount.value);
                var td   = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.taxdeduction.value);
                var ap   = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.amountpaid.value);
                var arwo = parseInt(document.TransactionForm.amountremainwithoffice.value);
                var result = (ea * td) / 100;
                var result1 = ea-result;
                var result2 = result1 - ap;
                document.TransactionForm.amountpayable.value = result1 ;
                document.TransactionForm.amountremainwithoffice.value = result2 ;

            }

        </script>
        <title>Calculate</title>
    </head>
    <body>

        <form action="#" name="TransactionForm" method="post">
            Earn Amount:<br />
            <input type="number" id="earnamount" name="earnamount" onChange="add()" ><br /><br />

            Tax Deduction:<br />

            <select name="taxdeduction" id="taxdeduction" onchange="add()">

                <option value="2">Two Percent</option>
                <option value="5">Five Percent</option>

            </select>
            <br /><br />

            Amount Payable:<br />
            <input type="number" id="amountpayable" name="amountpayable" ><br /><br />

            Amount Paid:<br />
            <input type="number" id="amountpaid" name="amountpaid" onchange="add()" ><br /><br />

            Amount Remain With Office:<br />
            <input type="number" id="amountremainwithoffice" name="amountremainwithoffice" ><br /><br />
            <input type="submit" value="Submit To Database" />
        </form>

    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Try with onChange instead of onchange :), on textbox , you have used onChange and on dropdown, you are using onchange (C capital)

Comment: same with onChange too

Comment: Added solution for this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The function name used here, add() is conflicting with the HTMLSelectElement add method - 
[See here](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_select_add.asp). There is a javascript error generated by your code which says--

```
TypeError: Not enough arguments to HTMLSelectElement.add.
```

I do not have much details on the error.

Changing the method name to something else will work. See this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/QkMh5/)

Just change your method name to something else. For eg. change add() to addThis()

Comment: No problem, other solutions given here will also work. But you should know why it was not working :)

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this

**Fiddle:** [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/sid_m/Mg4Kq/)

```
<select id="taxdeduction" onchange="myfun()">
<option value="2">Two Percent</option>
<option value="5">Five Percent</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work correctly, have a look here: http://jsfiddle.net/jpkhw/

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function populateList() {
    alert("Test");
}
</script>

<select onchange="populateList();">
<option>1</option>
<option>2</option>
</select>​
```

Or here: [select onclick onchange not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11707190/select-onclick-onchange-not-working)

Comment: WARNING: add is a function defined by JavaScript. It can be confusing ;)

Answer (score 0):

Always register your handlers using javascript , and avoid inline event handling , registering your event handler using JS solves it :-

```
window.onload =function (){
var p1 = document.getElementById("taxdeduction");
if (p1.addEventListener) {
pl.addEventListener("change", add, false);
} else {
pl.attachEvent('onchange', add);
}
};
```

Here is you working code - [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x5S3L/)

[Reference for source](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800310/add-event-handler-to-html-element-using-javascript)