# Can't get button to disappear

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to get this button to disappear when it is clicked, however, it does nothing when clicked

HTML

```html
<button id="startButton" onclick="startButton()">
   <img src="Img\MainMenu\button(play).png"> 
</button>

<script type="text/javascript" src="Client\js\placeholder.js"></script>
```

JavaScript

```js
startButton.onclick = function startButton() { // when start button is clicked
   startButton.style.display = "none";
};
```

Comment: Please take the [tour] and read [ask]. Also might want to look at the [help center article on how to format code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Add event handler to HTML element using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9800310/add-event-handler-to-html-element-using-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should learn a bit more about [HTML](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML) and [JavaScript](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/javascript) before you start coding. Your code has some fundamental errors.

To reference an element uniquely in JavaScript, you'll need to use [`document.getElementById`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById):

> The [`Document`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document) method **`getElementById()`** returns an [`Element`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element) object representing the element whose [`id`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/id) property matches the specified string. Since element IDs are required to be unique if specified, they're a useful way to get access to a specific element quickly.
>
> If you need to get access to an element which doesn't have an ID, you can use [`querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/querySelector) to find the element using any [selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/CSS_selector).

Source: [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementById)

```html
<button id="startButton">
   <img src="Img\MainMenu\button(play).png"> 
</button>

<script>
  const $startButton = document.getElementById('startButton')

  $startButton.onclick = () => {
    $startButton.style.display = 'none'
  }
</script>
```

Comment: i can see that your answer works here, however when i copy your code verbatim in VS and the button still wont disappear

Comment: @ethan1208 you are probably not implementing it correctly. Copy and paste my updated HTML into your `.html` file and run

Comment: thanks alot works now! still baffled as to why this wasnt working in my js file, as ideally i dont want all my code in the html, but thank you none the less :)

Comment: May be worth actually *detailing* the errors, lest your first paragraph may be seen as condescension. I'm sure that wasn't your intent but it comes across a little like that. For example (and I freely admit I don't know enough JS to know this to be the case so feel free to educate me), you could say "there is no automatic association between the button with ID `"startButton"` and the JS `startButton` variable, the latter is simply `undefined`. Here's some code that explicitly associates a variable with an ID:".

Comment: @paxdiablo I didn't mean to sound condescending. Whilst your explanation, is true, it sounds rather technical for a beginner, and my answer help the OP anyhow.

Comment: No problems, Aryan, I wasn't proposing that actual text, it was just meant to be an example of something you *could* say. I'd expect you to put it in your own words even if it *was* correct.